# Kaltura CE exact file location after transcoding and how to change transcoded file location

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, kaltura

I have installed Kaltura CE 4 days before on ubuntu 16.04 and all is working smooth.

By default Kaltura CE is installed in the root/opt (partition/directory) and the same partition is being used by my operating system Ubuntu 16.04, and this partition having less space than required actual space.

My another directory/partition which is "/home" have terabyte of space where I want to save my uploaded videos and after transcoding I want them to be saved inside "/home/kaltura" so they can be staying in good space partition.

I have tried to achieve this by enabling "Remote Storage" and during configure, i selected local storage and inside "Storage Base Directory:" i have given path "/home/kaltura" but I think Kaltura CE is not saving transcoded files inside my mentioned path.

Kindly help and guide that how can I change uploaded videos and transcoded videos files path/location please?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you would be better off relocating your whole installation to your home partition by symlinking /opt/kaltura to /home/kaltura.

Remote storage can use a different storage path, but will also require you to reconfigure your video delivery options for streaming and processing and is not intended for use on a local system.